# Opening image and closing it, outer program

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I'm trying to open and close a picture. Open it at the beginning of the loop and close it at the end of the loop. So far I've only managed to open the image, however for the closing I couldn't find the right options.
For opening I'm using

```
img =  os.startfile("image.jpg")
```

and for closing I've tried

```
img.close()
```

I've also tried

```
os.close("image.jpg")
```

How does one do this?

Comment: You cannot do this easily. `startfile()` just indirectly launches the associate application.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but if you don't mind me asking, what is the hard way of doing the open/close process.

Comment: You might be able to do it with a third-party module like [`pynput`](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) to control the application or possibly by making some OS-specific calls (via [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes)) to close it.

Answer (score 0):

Something in that direction:

```
import subprocess
import os
import signal
import time

image_viewer = "name of the image viewer program"
pid = subprocess.Popen([image_viewer, "image.jpg"]).pid
time.sleep(5)
os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

You need to know the name of an application used to view the image.

If it's just about displaying an image, you can also use a GUI toolkit like tkinter.

Comment: I don't know whether something similar is available in Python, but you can use [AssocQueryString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-assocquerystringw) to determine the default application associated with a given file extension.